# How to refresh "Tasks" in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, task

I inherited a program with a lot of `//TODO:` messages, which i expected would show up under `Tasks`.

Unfortunately, that pane is empty. Is there a way to refresh it for the current project?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The tasks tags in *.java files are scanned automatically by Eclipse compiler. You can simply refresh your project and then click on the Project / Clean... menu. Also check that task tags are not disabled in the project settings under Java Compiler / Task Tags and your Tasks or Markers view in Eclipse configured to show tasks for an entire project and not only selected element.

Comment: Perfect. "Clean" did it. Thanks Eugene

Answer (score 1):

There are two different views in eclipse. One is Tasks and the other is Task List. The latter shows build tasks using Mylyn. So for those who are looking for TODO list in java, please open Tasks in General view. Do a project clean if the list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Eugene's answer: A simple "Clean" is not enough, you have to build the project too.

(I do not use "Build Automatically", so I have to explicitly check "Start a build immediately" to get the Tasks View refreshed.)

Answer (score 0):

The Clean method suggested by Eugene didn`t work for me, later I figured out that I didn't save the file, after saving it (ctrl+s) the Tasks view refreshed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the "Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers" you are using then "Project -> C/C++ Index -> Rebuild" will do the trick rather than Project clean/build.